# Get current GPS location on android

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, currentlocation

Maybe look similar with many questions posted here but none of old solutions don't work anymore. I tested all and in all cases crash my application.

I need to display current user location in my MapFragment.

I try to use this code found on net:

```
LocationManager locationManager;
```

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
```

```
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
```

but my application crash. He stop running before displaying anything.

The problem is here :

```
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

What I do wrong? This is my first android application.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with the crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Most likely a SecurityException.  If your target api is 23 or higher, you will need to do a runtime location permission check.  Take a look at the linked duplicate for more details.